# Nginx - change the welcome page

Tags: nginx

I started an nginx container and would like to modify the content of the default page.
I changed the file `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` 
Unfortunately nginx still shows me the usual welcome page when I curl localhost.

How would I change the default page in nginx? 
I disabled cache in nginx via `sendfile  off;`

Comment: Have you checked that the file really has another content, because if you don't have reconfigured root this should work

Comment: I really double checked and even deleted the file

Comment: You said nginx container, do you use docker

Comment: Yes I do use docker

Comment: How do you change it, with something like `COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html`. And have you checked with `docker exec -it container cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`. Can you post your Dockerfile and config

Comment: I entered the container via `docker exec -it container \bin\bash` and modified the file inside the container. There is nothing in my dockerfile except of `docker run ....`

Comment: Ok, but somewhere must be a mistake because `docker run -p 80:80 --name test -d nginx && docker exec -it test sh -c 'echo hello world > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html'` works

Comment: Ghm Julian, you seem to be right. Thank you. I will investigate further, but now I know, that I am modifying the right file.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you did something like this in your Dockerfile:

`COPY ./index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

Try this instead:

```
COPY ./index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```